# Using Python splitlines() to convert a text file into a list while also combining some lines into single items in the list

Tags: python, python-re, txt

I am working to convert text files that were originally meant to be used with a VBA application into string lists for a new Python application. Each text file has "vectors" on separate lines with multiple strings, but I am just giving each one a single string for simplicity. The problem I am encountering is when a vector takes up multiple lines due to the line character limit of Excel/VBA. Here is an example :

> vector(1)="This is the first vector that only takes 1 line!"
>
> vector(2)="This is **some of** the text for vector 2 but it continues!"
>
> vector(2)= vector(2) & "This is the continuation of the text for
> vector 2!"
>
> vector(3)= "This is a new vector with only a single line!"

What I have tried to do is iterate through the list created by splitlines() to create a new list that is concatenated by trying to look back at the previous line to see if it has the same "vector(x)" label then joining the strings before appending to my final list. However, it then adds the unfinished string **and** the joined string to the list. Here is the code I am using:

```
import os
import re

Lines = open(doc).read().splitlines()
New_Lines = []
previous_label = 0
vector_label = 0
previous_contents = 0
vector_contents = 0
for z, vector_check in enumerate(Lines, 1):
    if vector_check.startswith("vector"):
        v_split = re.split(r"=", vector_check)
        previous_label = vector_label
        vector_label = v_split[0]
        previous_contents = vector_contents
        vector_contents = v_split[1]
    else :
        continue
    # print(vector_label)
    if previous_label != vector_label:
        repeat = 0
        New_Lines.append(vector_contents)
    else :
        repeat += 1
        vec_split_2 = re.split(r"&", v_split[1])
        vector_contents = previous_contents[:-1] + " " + vec_split_2[1][2:]
        New_Lines.append(vector_contents)
        print(vector_contents)
        continue
i = 1
for obj in New_Lines:
    print("vector_CRS(" + str(i) + ")=" + obj)
    i += 1
```

Gives the results:

> vector_CRS(1)="This is the first vector that only takes 1 line!"
>
> vector_CRS(2)="This is **some of** the text for vector 2 but it
> continues!"
>
> vector_CRS(3)="This is **some of** the text for vector 2 but it
> continues! This is the continuation of the text for vector 2!"
>
> vector_CRS(4)= "This is a new vector with only a single line!"

I have also tried looking forward in the list (that is why the enumerate is there) but the results were worse than these. This is the last piece of the "puzzle" for an overall larger script, and even though it feels simple like I am missing an easy answer, I've spent hours trying to fix this part.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file `vectors.txt`, which looks like this:

```
vector(1)="This is the first vector that only takes 1 line!"
vector(2)="This is some of the text for vector 2 but it continues!"
vector(2)= vector(2) & "This is the continuation of the text for vector 2!"
vector(3)= "This is a new vector with only a single line!"
```

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the vectors by their numbers, using a regex pattern. Then, using another regex, merge all the contents for every vector in a group:

```
def main():

    with open("vectors.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()

    def merge_vectors(lines):
        from itertools import groupby
        import re

        for _, group in groupby(lines, key=lambda line: re.match(r"vector\((\d+)\)", line).group(1)):
            yield " ".join(re.search("\"(.+)\"", item).group(1) for item in group)

    print(list(merge_vectors(lines)))
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
['This is the first vector that only takes 1 line!', 'This is some of the text for vector 2 but it continues! This is the continuation of the text for vector 2!', 'This is a new vector with only a single line!']
>>>
```

This assumes that the lines in the `vectors.txt` file will already by grouped together by the vector numbers. For example, it assumes that you cannot have something like:

```
vector(1)="Part of one"
vector(2)="Part of two"
vector(1)= vector(1) & "Also part of one"
```

---

EDIT - I've taken a look at the text file in your `repl.it`. I've made some changes to the regex patterns, and to the code in general - I've just made a few steps more explicit. The patterns are more lenient now, for example, something like `vector(2)= vector(2) & ""` will no longer throw an exception, but since there is no content between the double-quotes, it will be ignored. Lines that don't end with a double-quote are also handled. All the lines are also filtered before being processed so that only lines beginning with `vector_CRS(...)` are included, so you don't need to manually skip the first five or so lines anymore.

```
def main():

    import re

    line_pattern = r"vector_CRS\((?P<vector_number>\d+)\)"
    content_pattern = "\"(?P<content>.*)\"?"

    def is_vector_line(line):
        return re.match(line_pattern, line) is not None

    with open("vectors.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = list(map(str.strip, filter(is_vector_line, file)))

    def merge_vectors(lines):
        from itertools import groupby

        def key(line):
            return re.match(line_pattern, line).group("vector_number")

        def get_content(item):
            return re.search(content_pattern, item).group("content")

        for _, group in groupby(lines, key=key):
            yield " ".join(filter(None, map(get_content, group)))

    merged = list(merge_vectors(lines))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it will work great - I will test it out this afternoon.

Comment: It works wonderfully! The vectors will always be in order and grouped accordingly. One thing I noticed, though, is that the txt files I will be working with start the vectors on Line 6. Before that is some unnecessary data (name of the source file, name of the outgoing transmission, etc.). However, the vectors **always** start on line 6 - so I will try to build a workaround into your solution. Thank you again!

Comment: @KevinW. Glad to hear it! If they always start on line 6, you can simply slice `lines`, starting at the fifth index (the sixth line): `lines = file.read().splitlines()[5:]`

Comment: thank you again, but I did run into another issue. It seems that when I use it with the actual documents in question, it gives me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Here is a link to a replit I am using to test (the error comes up here and in my actual code) : [link](https://repl.it/@kevinwestermann/PrimaryForkedSolidstatedrive)

Comment: Line number 7 in your text file, the one that starts with `vector_CRS(1)= vector_CRS(1) & " compte pour ...`, doesn't have a closing double-quote.

Comment: Oh wow, what a simple explanation. I am going to have to make sure this was just a fluke because I am not the one who creates the txt files - I may have to find a fix if the end double-quote is not guaranteed. Thank you, again!

Comment: @KevinW. Sure, let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Hello again! I ended up adding a little loop that adds ' "' to the end of any line that does not already end in ". Now, I am testing the code with a wider (and less consistent) range of txt files and found that some contain what are essentially blank lines like so : 
`vector_CRS(12)= vector_CRS(12) & ""`

I am not sure if this is the line causing problems, but I getting the same error again (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ). I reused the replit from before if you want to take a look : [link](https://repl.it/@kevinwestermann/PrimaryForkedSolidstatedrive#main.py)

Comment: @KevinW. Thanks for sharing the `repl.it` link. I've edited my answer, and it should work with the text file you're working with. Let me know if it works.